# Can I get information about user's geolocation using javascript and google-analytics?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-analytics-api

Like the title, I'd like to gather information about geolocation of users from my existing snippet of Google Analytics, otherwise I'll have to use some extra js library that deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an extra library.

Google resolves user location on the server, so you cannot get it from the client side tracking code. And retrieving it via the API fails for a number of reasons, to start with that this would work only after the first hit and that it would be more work than using a specialized service.